# Switching "Screens" on Android App

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

So, I will have an ArrayList of Strings. Each String will represent a new "screen" of questions for the user. Each string will be passed to the server and it will return a list of questions to be asked. There will be a "Next" button to go to the next screen affiliated with the next string.

My question is, how would I implement this? I know three options:

1. Start a new activity for each, and I guess I would have to pass the ArrayList to each activity through SharedPrefs or Intent.
2. After the user is done with a screen, clear the current layout, and programatically fill the layout with the new questions
3. Use fragments for each.

I'm not sure what the best method is to complete this task. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I would create a single list view, update the list views model when the next button is clicked.

Comment: So, basically my "option 2". I figured this would be the most resourceful way because you don't have to start activities and/or switch fragments